# Нестандартная разметка в Windows приложениях

Tags: windows, winapi, winforms

Здравствуйте, у меня вопрос с помощью каких библиотек делается разметка, отличная от разметки  MFC, например браузер Google Chrome, существуют ли другие API библиотеки для создания GUI для Windows приложения, и можно ли включать в проект HTML файлы в качестве этой самой разметки? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хром для Windows сделан на основе WTL ([Windows Template Library](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library)), выбор пал на эту библиотеку, потому что она быстрая и поставляется под открытой лицензией. Интерфейс на ее основе небогатый, но исключительно быстрый.

Современный подход для написания интерфейсов под Windows - это платформа .NET, а конкретно WPF ([Windows Presentation Foundation](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)). При этом разметка интерфейса в идеале делается целиком в XAML.